# iOS 8 auto-sizing UITableViewCell with UITextView

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, ios8

iOS 8 introduced a way for tableViews to automatically adjust their cell's height based on their content (via AutoLayout).

```
// in viewDidLoad:
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
```

I already got it working with labels, images, etc.

**However, I can not figure out a way for the table view cell to grow automatically as soon as a cell's text view changes?**

Some more information on the setup:
The UITextView inside a cell has horizontal and vertical constraints to the table view cell's contentView. I also disabled scrolling for the text view.

I have also tried to change the height constraint of the cell manually, but the cell would not adopt those changes as well.

Comment: any progress on that one? I am looking to do the same...
Are you trying to get it to work while the user types? Or is the UITextView you are using not user-editable?

Answer (score 25):

If everything is set up properly (Auto Layout constraints) you **do not have to calculate anything yourself**.

All you have to do is disable UITextView's scrolling enabled property then on `textViewDidChange` call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`.

For a detailed explanation, check out a [post I wrote](http://candycode.io/self-sizing-uitextview-in-a-uitableview-using-auto-layout-like-reminders-app/) which also includes a working sample project.

Comment: Will it also work for UIWebView instead of UITextView ?

Comment: I'm not sure, UIWebView might have a different layout procedure, but it's worth a try!

Comment: Just removing scrolling enabled alone worked for me. thanks :)

Comment: What about static cells in UITableViewController?

Comment: I added this code in 'shouldChangeTextIn' and works fine. But not working for new line, and it grows after type a character //textview reside in tableview cell

Answer (score 4):

Reload the cell in the `textViewDidBeginEditing:` method of your `UITextViewDelegate`

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Obviously you should change the indexpath to the correct one for your cell. This will get the cell to update its constraints and resize itself.

Comment: It seems to work even without the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` which has the benefit of a keyboard to stay there

Comment: For me this approach results in the table view scrolling back to the top on every key stroke, which makes the text view basically unusable - anyone else have this problem? (iOS 8.1.2)

Comment: I should add, I have put this code into `textViewDidChange:`, not `textViewDidBeginEditing:` (what's the use in only setting the height when you start editing anyway?)

Comment: @James if you disable animations before and reenable after you can get rid of the annoying bouncing.

Answer (score 2):

The `tableView` has to be informed that the `textView` has changed. Other posts usually answer a "static" `textView` problem. However, if you are typing inside a table, the cell needs to grow as the `textView` grows as you type. The `textView` grows by disabling scrolling. The cell grows by setting the `textView`'s top and bottom constraints to those of the `contentView` of the cell. This will work once, once the table loads. However to tell the `tableView` to grow in real time, you have to do in the `textView`'s `didChange` delegate call

```
func textViewChanged(onCell cell: YourCustomCell) {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

This will work as you expect. The cell will grow as you type and there won't be a "bouncing".

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for Swift 4**

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    let oldSize = textView.frame.size
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
    if oldSize.height != newSize.height {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        var newFrame = textView.frame
        newFrame.size = CGSize(width: fmax(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
        textView.frame = newFrame
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I use, which solves the problem of the table view bouncing back after every keystroke.

```
 - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize oldSize = textView.frame.size;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
        // Resize cell only when cell's size changes, to prevent bouncing back and forth.
        if (oldSize.height != newSize.height) {
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
        CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
        textView.frame = newFrame;
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if the cell is at the bottom and you need to scroll to this point to be visible when starting to edit the row?

Comment: Yeah I'm also having that problem unfortunately. Have NO CLUE how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable scroll from your UITextView