# UITextView autogrowing with new line inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextview

I have a textview as shown in the picture below,[image]

I have given auto-layout constraint as top and bottom to thin line and leading to label and trailing to superview. Now whenever the return key is pressed the bounds of the textview automatically changes disobeying the constraints and the views get garbled as shown in picture below,
 [image]

I don't want this behaviour, Please help, thanks!.

Comment: Check [Autosizing in UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791167/ios-8-auto-sizing-uitableviewcell-with-uitextview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following example for growing textview.

https://github.com/MatejBalantic/MBAutoGrowingTextView

Comment: i don't need growing textview, i want to solve this auto growing issue which is breaking my view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Give a height constraint to you UITextView